# Gráficar grafico de barras con ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

estoy dibujando diagramas de barra básico y deseo que se vea la frecuencia pero al momento de visualizar el número correspondiente a la mayor frecuencia sale cortado, no se ve pero cuando acerco la imagen si se ve correctamente. Cómo puedo solucionar esto? ya que al exportar el gráfico, éste sale como se visualizó: cortado (ver imagen)
[image: Digrama con número de frecuencia]

```
## diagrama de Barra: Sexo ##

#para graficar diagrama de barra - cantidad visible
g<-ggplot(datos,aes(x=Sexo))
g+geom_bar(fill="darkorchid4",color="black")+labs(title="SEXO - INGRESANTES 
2015",x="Sexo",y="Frecuencia") 
+stat_count(aes(y=..count..,label=..count..),geom="text",vjust=-1)
```

También quería poner cada grupo de distinto color pero como no pude agregar sus correspondientes leyendas, lo dejé de un único color.

Comment: Buenas Claudia, ¿podrías añadir a tu pregunta la forma de generar el plot?

Comment: Buenas noches David, ya agregué el código y una consulta más. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, no logro reproducir el comportamiento de tu gráfico. Por defecto `ggplot` hace un buen trabaja en ubicar las etiquetas, como mucho puede "pegarlas" al techo de la zona sombreada, pero de ninguna manera las termina ocultando.  Al menos como te digo, con la ejecución por defecto. De cualquier forma lo que puedes hacer es ajustar el "Zoom" sobre el gráfico mediante `coord_cartesian()` puedes ajustar por ejemplo los limites `y` y hacerlos mayores a los calculados automáticamente, las barras se verán más pequeñas, pero dispondrás de más superficie para ubicar las etiqueta con el valor de la frecuencia:

```
datos <- data.frame(Sexo=c(rep(1,435), rep(2, 335)),  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ggplot(datos,aes(x=Sexo)) +
  geom_bar(fill="darkorchid4",color="black") +
  labs(title="SEXO - INGRESANTES 2015",x="Sexo",y="Frecuencia") +
  stat_count(aes(y=..count..,label=..count..),geom="text",vjust=-1) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-1,500))
```

Con `coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-1,500))` hacemos que el eje `y` se muestre desde `-1` a `500`, este último valor lo deberías ajustar manualmente o asignarle un porcentaje a el valor con la máxima frecuencia

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como última sugerencia, usa esta transformación sobre `Sexo` para hacer más clara la gráfica: `aes(x=factor(Sexo,labels = c("Femenino", "Masculino")))`

Comment: Muchas Gracias Patricio!. Ahora lo probaré pq las generé horizontal pq no lograba  solucionar el recorte.